# Trap or evaluate bad regular expression string at runtime in awk script

Tags: awk

How can I trap an error if a dynamic regular expression evaluation is bad like:

```
var='lazy dog'
# a fixed Regex here, but original is coming from ouside the script
Regex='*.'

#try and failed
if (var ~ Regex) foo
```

The goal is to manage this error as I cannot test the regex itself (it comes from external source). Using POSIX awk (AIX)

Comment: could you explain what you mean by `bad` here? `*.` will match `*` followed by any character (or perhaps that is how GNU awk treats it but other versions don't?)

Comment: normaly it fail '*' is a quantifier so missing something before. In my case, awk return a RC of 2 with message `awk: 0602-521 There is a regular expression error. ?*+ not preceded by valid expression.`

Comment: @Sundeep, awk provided by SUNWesu fails here too. It just crashes

Comment: Maybe change the title to _Evaluate validity of dynamic regular expression in awk_.

Comment: Is it not possible to check if your regex is valid before you use `awk`?

Comment: that's what i do actually but it's a bit heavy. I do a first awk that try and if return a RC > 0, the script don't run the second awk using it. It could be lot better if i can use something like a eval of a kind of try but could find such a trick inside awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ echo 'foo' |
awk -v re='*.' '
    BEGIN {
        cmd="awk --posix \047/" re "/\047 2>&1"
        cmd | getline rslt
        print "rslt="rslt
        close(cmd)
    }
    { print "got " $0 " but re was bad" }
'
rslt=awk: cmd. line:1: error: Invalid preceding regular expression: /*./
got foo but re was bad
```

I use gawk so I had to add `--posix` to make it not just accept that regexp as a literal `*` followed by any char. You'll probably have to change the awk command being called in `cmd` to behave sensibly for your needs with both valid and invalid regexps but you get the idea - to do something like an `eval` in awk you need to have awk call itself via system() or a pipe to getline. Massage to suit...

Oh, and I don't think you can get the exit status of `cmd` with the above syntax and you can't capture the output of a system() call within awk so you may need to test the re twice - first with system() to find out if it fails but redirecting it's output to /dev/null, and then on a failure run it again with getline to capture the error message.

Something like:

```
awk -v re='*.' '
    BEGIN {
        cmd="awk --posix \047/" re "/\047 2>&1"
        if ( system(cmd " > /dev/null") ) {
            close(cmd " > /dev/null")
            cmd | getline rslt
            print "rslt="rslt
            close(cmd)
        }
    }
    { print "got " $0 " but re was bad" }
'
```

Comment: i was suspecting that i have to pass to external process hoping to avoid this but seems i can't. thanks

Comment: Rights, I don't know of any way to avoid that.